# Assinging Values to a new column in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am unable to understand how values are assinged to a new column of a DataFrame

if my code is:

```
Frame3['Debt']=16.5
print Frame3

o/p is
     Year   State  POP  Debt
one    2000    Ohio  1.5  16.5
two    2001    Ohio  1.7  16.5
three  2002    Ohio  3.6  16.5
four   2001  Nevada  2.4  16.5
five   2002  Nevada  2.9  16.5
```

but if I assign

```
Frame5 =Frame3['Debt']=16.5
print Frame5
```

my o/p is:

```
16.5
```

Whats happening the above line of code??

but the code:
`Frame5 =Frame3` works

Comment: is this a pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write:

```
Frame5 = Frame3.loc[Frame3['Debt']== 16.5]
```

To subset your pandas DataFrame. Make sure that 'Debt' is a float.

Comment: I don't think this is an R data.frame.